# Why are there electric field lines outside the conductor but not inside?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, gauss-law, conductors

[image]

The Electric field at point P (for an electric slab) is given by $E_P=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$, however, since $E$ inside the metallic slab is zero, the electric field at point P is contributed by only one of the surface (near surface). So the electric field at P should be $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ and not $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$. Can someone argue why this electric field is $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Vivek Dhaka! First, the title of your post is unacceptable. Second, putting your problem in a picture and then asking one to read the problem statement from it is unacceptable. As is, this question will likely be downvoted and closed. I will edit the title for you. You'll need to edit the post to move the problem statement to text.

Answer (score 1):

The electric field at point $P$ is contributed by both the surfaces of (thick) conducting slab because you can't (completely) enclose the electric charge of slab by considering an imaginary surface on one side only.

Recall Gauss Law for Electrostatics: $\oint\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}=Q_{net}/\epsilon_o$. Where $dA$ is the differential area intercepted by the electric field lines generated by a net electric charge $Q_{net}$ which is (completely) enclosed by a closed surface (called Gaussian surface). $\oint\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}$ is the electric flux through differential area $dA$ of Gaussian surface.

The electric charge is distributed over the surface of a conductor so if we consider an imaginary Gaussian surface within a conductor it encloses no electric charge so the electric field inside conductor is zero.

Assuming the conducting slab is infinitely large & having a uniform charge density $\sigma$ is thick enough i.e. its two surfaces are well separated. 
Now, consider an imaginary closed cylindrical surface of cross-section area $A$ passing through point $P$ & slab on either side. The net electric charge enclosed will be $Q_{net}=2\sigma A$ considering electric charge on both the sides of slab. The electric lines intercept the cross-sectional area $2A$ of imaginary cylinder on both the sides  of slab (electric field lines don't intercept the curved surface of Gaussian cylinder so electric flux through curved surface is zero). Using Gauss Law
$$\oint\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}=\frac{Q_{net}}{\epsilon_o}$$
$$E\oint dA=\frac{2\sigma A}{\epsilon_o}$$
$$E(2A)=\frac{2\sigma A}{\epsilon_o}$$
$$E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_o}$$
Note: $E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_o}$ is the electric field by a very thin uniformly charged sheet

Answer (score 0):

You have a misconception. The field is the gradient of the potential. Inside the slab, the gradient is zero but the charges on both sides contribute to the potential, so charges on both sides contribute to the field outside the rod.